# How can I extract data from a dictionary by specifying a range of values?

Tags: python, dictionary, range

I have a dictionary,

```
{"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}
```

I want to extract the data from this dictionary whose values are in the range 20 - 30.

Example.    I want the output should be

```
apple:20   
banana:25
```

I was thinking to order the dictionary first by the values, but it does not seem to work.

I tried `dict= sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])`
but the output shows like this:

```
[("apple", "20"), ("orange" , "40"), ("banana" , "25"), ("mango" , "50")]
```

How can I get output as:

```
apple:20   
banana:25
```

Comment: For one thing your values are strings, not numbers, so won't compare correctly. For another it seems like you want to *filter*, not *sort*, the sequence of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample_dict={"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}
for name,num in sample_dict.items():
    if int(num) in range(20,31):
        print('%s: %s' %(name,num))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can  do the following:

```
> d = {"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}
> for item in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: int(i[1])):
>   print ': '.join(item)
apple: 20
banana: 25
orange: 40
mango: 50
```

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) sorts the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)'s items (which are key-value [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple)) by the value using a a specific sorting `key`.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}

for k, v in d.items():
    if 20 <= int(v) <= 30:
        print(k, ':', v, sep='')
```

prints

```
apple:20
banana:25
```

Answer (score 1):

With using of list comprehension you can extract `(key,values)` that their values (first cast to `int`) are in range 20-30 :

```
d = {"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}
[(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if  20 <= int(v) <= 30]
# [('banana', '25'), ('apple', '20')]
```

Then you can have your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Returns a dict `{'apple': '20', 'banana': '25'}`

`>>> d = {"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}`

`>>> {key: val for key,val in d.items() if 20 <= int(val) <= 30}`

`{'apple': '20', 'banana': '25'}`

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary comprehension:

```
the_dict = {"apple" : "20", "orange" : "40", "banana" : "25", "mango" : "50"}

new_dict = {the_dict.keys()[i]:the_dict.values()[i] for i in range(len(the_dict.values())) if int(the_dict.values()[i]) <= 30 and    int(the_dict.values()[i] >= 20)}

print new_dict
```

Comment: First, this will not work for Python 3, where `dict.<keys|values>` are non-indexible views that actually function more like sets. You are forced to call `list` which would remind you of this fact.  Second, this is a very inefficient solution. Since you are creating a *new list* each time you use these methods, for every iteration.  Also, even if it *were* desirable to do it this way, I would do it explicitly with loops, not using a 165 character-width nested comprehension construct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `set` to obtain fast membership testing. Doing so also eliminates the need to convert the dictionary's values to integers since the members of the `set` are strings:

```
d = {"apple": "20", "orange": "40", "banana": "25", "mango": "50"}
limits = set(str(n) for n in range(20, 31))

for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    if value in limits:
        print('{}:{}'.format(key, value))
```